# No output from sls create test

Tags: mocha.js, serverless

Kicking off some much overdue TDD with Serverless.

I've installed serverless-mocha-plugin as per https://serverless.com/blog/tdd-serverless/

When I try to sls create test -f  I dont get any output

I have tried a few different params to but no results. No test is created. I've tried SLS_DEBUG=true and nothing of interest is shown there either

The output of sls command shows the invoke test and create test functionality is available.

Anyone got any ideas on where start debugging this?

Comment: What does your serverless.yml file look like? What function name did you pass as a parameter to the `sls create test -f` command?

Answer (score 1):

your serveless might be outdated; update it via `npm install serverless -g`

and your plugin is outdated as well, try installing and adding in your serverless.yml file; jest is from mocha and they're test functionality are the same

```
plugins:
 - serverless-jest-plugin
```

then install via

```
sls plugin install --name serverless-jest-plugin
```

then try the create test again